# Авторское двоеточие

Tags: пунктуация

Есть такое? Если да - то вместо какого знака оно употребляется?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть. Например, в бессоюзных сложных предложениях по правилам ставится тире, если вторая часть заключает в себе следствие, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова поэтому, тогда), например: Я умираю — мне не к чему лгать (Тургенев).

Но в  произведениях писателей-классиков, изредка и в современной художественной литературе, вместо тире в рассматриваемом случае встречается двоеточие, например: Делать было нечего: Марья Ивановна села в карету и поехала во дворец… (Пушкин); Мы ехали сзади: никто не видал (Лермонтов); Мелкий дождь сеет с утра: выйти невозможно (Тургенев); Володина лошадь хромала: папа велел оседлать для него охотничью (Л. Толстой); Заботы, огорчения, неудачи измучили бедного батюшку до крайности: он стал недоверчив, желчен… (Достоевский).

Это авторское двоеточие.

Авторским можно считать и двоеточие перед однородными членами, хотя обобщающего слова перед ними нет. Функцию обобщающего слова в этих случаях выполняет сказуемое, непосредственно предшествующее однородным членам — подлежащим. Ср. в деловой и научной речи: На заседании присутствовали:..; Для получения смеси нужно взять:….

Авторам нужно предупредить, что дальше идёт перечисление, и они ставят двоеточие:

Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженой формой и еще кое-какие привлекательные узелки и коробочки (Л. Толстой);Тут были: Павел, чухонец, штабс-капитан Ярошевич, фельдфебель Максименко, красная фуражка, дама с белыми зубами, доктор (Чехов); Спальные места отделены столбами, на этих столбах, поддерживающих крышу, висят: одежда, ружья и связки шкурок (Коптяева).

Answer (score 0):

**Существует ли авторское двоеточие?** Само сочетание звучит как-то необычно (чаще встречается авторское тире), но давайте поговорим об этих авторских знаках.

1) Давно уже известны  правила постановки тире и двоеточия в БСП и в предложениях с обобщающими словами, и также давно известно, что **нет между ними четких границ.** Так что же, нарушаются правила, используется авторская пунктуация? Нет,  не в этом дело, **просто в формальные правила никак не помещается наша русская речь.** Вот тогда и приходится говорить о пунктуации авторской, если писатель или ученый-лингвист интуитивно понимает, что формальное правило в данном случае не работает.

**2) Попробуем убедиться в этом на одном из  примеров.** Всем известно, что в БСП отношения "причина-следствие" должны обозначаться тире.  Розенталь [XXX. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В БЕССОЮЗНОМ СЛОЖНОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm)  "Тире ставится, если вторая часть заключает в себе следствие, вывод из того, о чем говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова поэтому, тогда), например: **Я умираю – мне не к чему лгать** (Тургенев)".

3) **А давайте попробуем поставить здесь двоеточие:** "**Я умираю: мне не к чему лгать"**. Вроде бы неплохо получилось, и вот почему. К сожалению, Розенталь не выделял тире **присоединительное и разделительное**. Названия эти чисто условные, но разница принципиальная: перед разделительным  тире делается повышение тона (**предложение резко делится на две части**),  а перед присоединительным тире делается понижение тона. И такое же понижение тона (только со значительной паузой) делается **перед двоеточием**. Поэтому **присоединительное тире и двоеточие легко заменяют друг друга.**

4) **Почитаем Розенталя дальше:**

**Примечание.** В произведениях писателей-классиков, изредка и в современной художественной литературе, вместо тире в рассматриваемом случае встречается **двоеточие**, например: Делать было нечего: Марья Ивановна села в карету и поехала во дворец... (Пушкин); Мы ехали сзади: никто не видал (Лермонтов); Мелкий дождь сеет с утра: выйти невозможно (Тургенев); Володина лошадь хромала: папа велел оседлать для него охотничью (Л. Толстой); **Заботы, огорчения, неудачи измучили бедного батюшку до крайности: он стал недоверчив, желчен... (Достоевский).** (Вот такое авторское тире, которое как-то даже сложно называть авторским).

И в заключение попробуем заменить двоеточие в одном из приведенных примеров тире: Сейчас его сердце открыто для всех. **А измучает его жизнь, изломает – станет недоверчивым.** Это разделительное тире, его двоеточием не заменишь.

Answer (score 0):

> **Авторское двоеточие.**
>
> Есть такое?

**Иногда встречается**.

К примеру, у Ахматовой ("Сивилла"):

> *Сивилла: выжжена, сивилла: ствол.*
>
> *Все птицы вымерли, но Бог вошел.*
>
> *Сивилла: выпита, сивилла: сушь.*
>
> *Все жилы высохли: ревностен муж!*
>
> *Сивилла: выбыла, сивилла: зев*
>
> *Доли и гибели! — Древо меж дев.*

Или у Солженицына ("На изломах"):

> ***Но:*** болтовня одна или политической власти хотят.

У него же ("Раковый корпус"):

> *Запомните. **Люди живут:** идейностью и общественным благом*.